# Eulclid's Algorithm : Python code returns None at the end of recursion

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to implement [*Euclid's algorithm* for computing the greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid's_algorithm) using recursion. Below is the code for the same.

```
def euclid(a,b):
    if a>b:
        r=a%b
        if (r == 0):
            return b
        else:
            a=b
            b=r
            euclid(a,b)

print(euclid(20,4)) # Returns 4
print(euclid(20,8)) # Returns None
```

For the first data set, I get the correct result. But for `euclid(20,8)` I get a return of `None`.

While checking in the debugger, I did see the return value of `b` become `4` but then for some reason, my code jumps to `euclid(a,b)` and returns `None`.

The major takeaway here would be to understand why the code does not return `4` but jumps to the `euclid(a,b)` and return `None`.

Please refrain from giving alternative code solutions but you are very much encouraged to point out the reason for the current behaviour of the code.

Comment: `if a>b:` is superfluous. You can safely remove it. So remove if and add `return` to recursive call.

Comment: Well, that condition ensures that I am dividing a bigger number by a smaller number. In fact, I was going to add an if for `b>a` but that is not the point I am focussing in my query here.

Comment: I understand your point. But just think what would happen if that condition is not there. Adding superfluous conditions to code violates DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principle many times and may cause surprise bugs. (For ex. running your code to print `euclid(4, 20)`.

Comment: You are right. We can safely remove that `if` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that code to return `None` at some point is that in your control flow you eventually end up in a situation where there is no `return` statement, e.g. for `a <= b` in your first `if` or when `r != 0` in your second `if`. The default behavior of Python in that case is to return `None`, as you seems to have discovered the hard way.

```
def euclid(a,b):
    if a>b:
        r=a%b
        if (r == 0):
            return b
        else: # <--- no `return` in this branch!
            a=b
            b=r
            euclid(a,b)
    # else:  # <--- no `return` in this branch!
    #     ...
```

---

Here is an updated version of your code, that addresses that and also a number of other issues:

- the name of the function should be meaningful: [Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid) is kind of popular and there is a bunch of things named after him, better specify that you actually want to compute the [greatest common divisor (GCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)
- the first `if` is not really needed, as it is taken care of by the subsequent code: computing `r` and the recursive call will take care of swapping `a` and `b` if `a < b`, and if `a == b` then `r == 0`, so you `b` is being returned directly
- `a = b` and `b = r` are useless, do not use them, just have your recursive call use `b` and `r` directly
- the second `if` can be written more clearly in one line

```py
def gcd_euclid_recursive(a, b):
    r = a % b
    return gcd_euclid_recursive(b, r) if r else b


gcd_euclid_recursive(120, 72)
# 24

gcd_euclid_recursive(64, 120)
# 8
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your answer by making it more beginner-friendly. That is one of the reasons why I was specific of not welcoming alternate solutions. Also, I do realize there are some condition related shortcomings but that's not what the focus of my query here.

Comment: @mishsx what is not clear / you would improve?

Comment: At the same time you show good effort in answering the question in detail so I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: I did not state anything about clarity. In future, if someone visits this page, he/she should understand more on what went wrong rather finding a backdoor to the current problem by alternate approaches. Sure that will make others learn but it deviates the focus from what went wrong in the code. Other than that your answer was well -versed and detailed.

Comment: @mishsx I have added your code with comments to show visually where it went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually *return* anything in the `else` path so it just assumes you know best and returns `None` for you.

The only reason you get `4` for `print(euclid(20,4))` is because `4` is a factor of `20` so never *uses* the `else` path. Instead it returns `b` immediately. For anything else, the thing returned from the first recursive call to `euclid()` will always be `None` (even if a lower call to that function returns something, you throw it away when returning from the first call).

You need `return euclid(a,b)` rather than just `euclid(a,b)`.

---

As an aside (this isn't necessary to answer your specific question but it goes a long way toward improving the implementation of the code), I'm not a big fan of the `if something then return else …` construct since the `else` is totally superfluous (if it didn't return, the `else` bit is automatic).

Additionally, you don't need to assign variables when you can just change what gets passed to the next recursive level.

Taking both those into account (and simplifying quite a bit), you can do something like:

```
def euclid(a, b):
    if b == 0: return a
    return euclid(b, a % b)
```

Comment: Resolved the issue. BUt i believe you can improve your answer by pasting my code on pythontutor.com

Comment: Why the return value of 4 suddenlys jumps to the euclid() in else is what confused me in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an indentation error and one path is missing in your code(r!=0). It should be

```
def euclid(a,b):
    if a>=b:
        r=a%b
        if (r == 0):
            return b
        return euclid(b, r)
    else:
        return euclid(b, a)
```

Comment: There is no indentation error whatsoever, I double-checked it again my friend.

Comment: Give me an example dataset which you think would fail my code. That would explain and help to visualize if there is something wrong about the condition you mention.

Comment: In your code please try `print(euclid(20,20))` there is no else path and first if condition should be greater than or equal otherwise you will miss some cases.